# Generics: How to derive from one of two classes?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following c# classes:

```
class A : Object
{
   foo() {}
}

class B : Object
{
   foo() {}
}
```

I want to write a generic method that applies to both:

```
void bar<T>(T t)
{
  t.foo();
}
```

this does not compile complaining the foo() is not a member of T. I can add a constraint for T to derive from one of the classes:

```
void bar<T>(T t) where T : A
```

but how can I have it for both?

Comment: Diverting little from the question. 
If this is the use case, does it still make sense have a generic method ? 
Why not simply implement interface 'IFoo' to both A and B and declare the method as 
void bar( IFoo f) {
  f.foo();
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put you can't.  There are a couple of approaches to work around this problem though.

The most common is to use an interface.  Say `IMyType`

```
interface IMyType { void foo(); }
class A : IMyType ...
class B : IMyType ...

void bar<T>(T t) where T : IMyType {
  t.Foo();
}
```

This is a bit heavy weight though is it requires a metadata change for a solution.  A cheaper approach is to provide a lambda expression which calls the appropriate function.

```
void bar<T>(T t, Action doFoo) {
  ...
  doFoo();
}

var v1 = new A();
var v2 = new B();
bar(v1, () => v1.Foo());
bar(v2, () => v2.Foo());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define an interface:

```
interface IFoo
{
   void foo();
}


class A : IFoo
{
   public void foo() {}
}

class B : IFoo
{
   public void foo() {}
}
```

And your generic method:

```
void bar<T>(T t) where T:IFoo
{
  t.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface that contains the *foo* method, and have classes A & B implement that interface.  Then define an interface constraint on your generic type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that unless you:

1. Derive from a base class
2. Derive from an interface

I prefer the interface because it doesn't force you to share behavior:

```
public interface IHasFoo
{
    void foo();
}

public class B : IHasFoo // you don't need to explicitly subclass object
{
    public void foo()
    {
    }
}

public class A : IHasFoo // you don't need to explicitly subclass object
{
    public void foo()
    {
    }
}

void bar<T>(T t) where T : IHasFoo
{
    t.foo(); // works
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in .NET 4.0 using `dynamic`.

```
void bar(dynamic t)
{
  t.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making this generic? Just overload the method.

```
 void bar(A a) { a.Foo(); }
 void bar(B b) { b.Foo(); }
```

Generics are there so that you can make potentially infinite `bar()` methods.